# C++ - Convert AM/PM time string to posix time ptime

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to convert a time string to `boost::posix_time::ptime` object, but the conversion is not working.This is the function thats being used.

```
std::string Parser::getFormattedDate(std::string datetime)
{
  std::stringstream date_strm, date_res;
  boost::posix_time::ptime pt;
  boost::posix_time::time_input_facet *facet = new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet( "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S %p" );

  date_strm.imbue( std::locale( std::locale(), facet ));
  date_strm << datetime;
  date_strm >> pt;

  date_res << pt.date().year() << "-" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << pt.date().month().as_number()
           << "-" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << pt.date().day() << " "
           << pt.time_of_day().hours() << ":" << pt.time_of_day().minutes() << ":" << pt.time_of_day().seconds();

  return date_res.str();
}
```

With a input time string of `2016-Feb-29 2:00:00 AM`, this function is returning `Thu Dec 3 04:00:54 287564` which is obviously not correct. How can i get the correct date time from that input ? In this case the correct date time should be `2016-02-29 02:00:00`

The `time_input_facet` thats being used in this function for the required conversion is `"%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S %p"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html) says:

[image]

The exclamation mark means:

> The following tables list the all the flags available for both date_time IO as well as strftime. Format flags marked with a single asterisk (*) have a behavior unique to date_time. ***Those flags marked with an exclamation point (!) are not usable for input (at this time)***. The flags marked with a hash sign (#) are implemented by system locale and are known to be missing on some platforms. The first table is for dates, and the second table is for times.

So you'll have to manually parse the am/pm part if you must support this using just Boost Datetime

Maybe you can look at Boost Locale for this task: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/locale/doc/html/formatting_and_parsing.html

This works for me:

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

static std::locale s_loc = boost::locale::generator{}.generate("");

std::string getFormattedDate(std::string datetime) {
    boost::posix_time::ptime pt;
    using namespace boost::locale;

    std::stringstream ss(datetime);
    ss.imbue(s_loc);

    date_time dt;
    if (ss >> as::ftime("%Y-%b-%d %I:%M:%S %p") >> dt) {
        ss.str("");
        ss.clear();
        ss << as::ftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") << dt;
        return ss.str();
    }

    throw std::bad_cast();
}

int main() {
    std::locale::global(s_loc);
    for (auto s : { "2016-Feb-29 02:06:22 AM", "2016-Mar-29 02:06:22 PM" })
        std::cout << s << " -> " << getFormattedDate(s) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Bye\n";
}
```

Prints

```
2016-Feb-29 02:06:22 AM -> 2016-02-29 02:06:22
2016-Mar-29 02:06:22 PM -> 2016-03-29 14:06:22
Bye
```

Comment: Perfect. Works flawlessly !!  Thanks a lot for your help. I've seen that %p ! before in the boost I/O facets , and realized that the input_time_facet won't work with the AM/PM strings. Hence i posted a question here hoping someone might have figured this out.

Comment: @Maxx it would have been classy to just mention that. Would have saved me a significant amount of time (because I don't assume people can't read documentation before posting SO...)

Comment: Yes i understand. But after going through the doc for the input_time_facet and Stackoverflow i was getting no proper solution to this, hence i felt the need to post this..

Comment: @Maxx I just told you I wasted time because you didn't mention you already knew input-facet doesn't support AM/PM. You can "feel the need" to post whatever you want (no one questioned the goal), but you didn't have to omit that information. You'd have gotten the same answer **but quicker** and I'd have been happier. Simply put: just say sorry. It's ok, I've already answered. We're all here to learn.

Comment: Of course we are, and i apologize for not including that information. Its just that i couldn't find a proper way to handle the AM/PM so in a panic i forgot to mention that.